# Caching with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I am new to the caching thing, and i want to cache (just when app is still open) arrays of data.
Can anyone tell me how to do it using NSMutableDictionnary ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSMutableDictionary` is a collection type that allows you to store data via *key*/*value* pairs. The key of the pair is what you search for and the value is what you want to retrieve. If you have a key named `dob` you may expect a value of something like "1-19-1989".

If you want to cache something right at the beginning of start up you would do it in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your AppDelegate file. It would go something like this...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//// Get whatever data you need
NSString *key = @"dob";
NSString *value = @"1-19-89";

// Place into a dictionary like this
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{key: value};

// And for NSMutableDictionary 
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[mutableDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];

return YES; 

}
```

And as @Abhinav said, from their you can either store to `NSUserDefaults` for small data and I would advise `CoreData` for large amounts of data.

Comment: ok i get what you meant .. this is helpful .. but is there another way than doing it in appDelegate ? the thing is that i have a list of items in a collection view then those items when pressed might have inside of them another items to store in collectionview , if not, details will open in a simple textfield, i want to cache those items when loaded from the internet (when the collectionview is shown)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to persist the data in different application sessions like quit and re-launch should restore the previous data. There are following ways you can achieve this:

1. Use User Defaults - not advisable to use for big chunk of data
2. File System Caching - Use NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver to save/fetch the data from file system.
3. Core Data - Backed by file system or SQL.

If you are looking for data persistence during current session then use Singleton class with NSMutableDictionary property holding on that data. This property can be accessed all across the app and would behave like a local cache.